# How to convert an Integer automatically to my type?

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

What I want to do is the following:

```
class myNumber
    sub new(i as integer)
    end sub
end class

sub main()
    Dim listl as new List(of myNumber)
     listl.add(1)
     ' some more stuff ... '
end sub
```

so the question is what kind of function do I have to override, or what attribute do I need to add, so that the code in main compiles?

Its not for any specific purpose, just curiosity.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `listl.add(new myNumber(1))` ?

Comment: that would be one way, but i'm interested in simply using listl.add(1) and then the program automatically calls the constructor with for an integer

Comment: you create a `List(Of myNumber)` which exists only in that sub, by the way, so to add to the list, you need to create New `MyNumbers`.  It contains `MyNumber` types not integers

Comment: sorry I meant that myNumber automatically calls the constructor that has only an Integer as parameter  
Similar to the example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1
where they use "Dim posBigInt as BigInteger = 0"
That should be the same principle or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide an [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kca3w8x6.aspx) from `System.Int32` to `MyNumber`. In this case i would also use a `Structure` instead of a class since it represents an immutable value type.

In VB.NET you have to override the `Widening CType operator` to create an implicit conversion:

```
Public Structure MyNumber

    Public Sub New(value As Int32)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Property Value As System.Int32

    Public Overloads Shared Widening Operator CType(value As Int32) As MyNumber
        Return New MyNumber(value)
    End Operator

End Structure
```

Now this works:

```
Dim listl as new List(of MyNumber)
listl.Add(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your `Add` slightly to create a new instance of `myNumber` passing in the required integer value in the constructor:

```
Class myNumber
    Sub New(i As Integer)

    End Sub
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim listl As New List(Of myNumber)
    listl.Add(New myNumber(1))
    'some more stuff
End Sub
```